# How do I delay my application logic to execute until persisted data get rehydrated? Redux Persist, React, Redux Toolkit, RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux, Redux Toolkit, and Redux Persist in my project.

I have a store configured with redux, redux toolkit and redux persist.
One portion of the store's slice is persisted with Redux Persist, which is access token.
My api logic/services needs the access token to work which is in a file.

The problem here is: my api logic is executing first before the persisted data get stored. I have the solution to work on component because it is wrapped using PersistGate,

but I want to do it in another file.

Here's the code:
[Get Redux-Persists' persisted accessToken into RTK querys API definition file - Store Rehydration other than in Component Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74333561/5700946)

The problem here is: my api logic is executing first before the persisted data get stored. I have the solution to work on component because it is wrapped using PersistGate,

Comment: facing the same problem, any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution to how I approached at first. But later I have decided make it work around like on redux toolkit documentation example. But that work but my initial architecture doesn't go with this. So I have used Axios hooks then RTK query.